# How Internet knows my NS Server IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name

If I own a domain name (for example: mydomain.com), and I setup my own ns server ns1.mydomain.com with a public IP (for example: 1.2.3.4), I registered the ns1.mydomain.com to the registrar's system.

I have a record in my ns server: [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) which points to a IP (for example: 1.2.3.5), if someone from Internet wants to access my [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), how do they know the ns server of my domain: ns1.mydomain.com is 1.2.3.4?  Since they need to know that 1.2.3.4 contains all the data of my domain, but technically how do they know it?

When someone wants to access [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), they will get the ns server name (ns1.mydomain.com) from the registrar's system, but then how do they know it is 1.2.3.4?

Thank you!

*This is the first time I need to manage a self-own ns server

**Actually my domain has 2 ns servers and they have been running for years, but we need to change the public IP of ns2 soon. I need to understand more about it in order to make the changes without major problems/mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **very simplified picture** of how DNS work:

You have 13 top level DNS server, named root servers. And your resolver know how to access them. These 13 servers know which servers support `.com` (in your case) zone. You ask them (these which support `.com`) about `mydomain.com`. Some of these servers (which support `.com`) answer with the DNS servers of `mydomain.com`. And resolver ask these DNS servers (from answer) about `www.mydomain.com`

For more information you can visit [this page](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/).

Answer (score 0):

"In this case, the name server providing the delegation must also provide one or more IP addresses for the authoritative name server mentioned in the delegation."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records